# how to re-initiate iteration after changing a variable

Tags: python

I am learning python and CS via the MIT OCW material.  Doing this for fun btw because I think its interesting.  I am trying to tackle a problem set where for a given credit card balance (ex. $1200) and interest rate (18%), what would minimum monthly payment need to be pay it off completely in 12 months or less.  Start with $100 and if more or less is needed, change it increments of $10.  In my code below, if the initial start of $100 doesnt work, i dont know how to increase it by 10 and THEN start iterating again.  Im not even sure starting with a "While" is the best approach.  Im sure the pros could code this up in like 2 lines but I would appreciate if anyone were to help, they do it the long way so a novice like myself could follow it.

```
balance = float(input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:"))
annual_rate = float(input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:"))

monthly_interest_rate = annual_rate / 12.0
minimum_monthly_payment = 100
updated_balance_each_month = balance * (1 + monthly_interest_rate) - minimum_monthly_payment

month = 1

while month <= 12:
    month += 1
    updated_balance_each_month = updated_balance_each_month * (1 + monthly_interest_rate) - minimum_monthly_payment
    if updated_balance_each_month <= 0:
        print ("Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:", minimum_monthly_payment)
        print ("Number of months needed:",month)
        print (round(updated_balance_each_month,2))
        break
    else:
        minimum_monthly_payment += 10
```

Comment: You should maybe use two loops. The hint is within your logical reasoning: "*increase it by 10 and THEN start iterating again*". If you have to start iterating again, 99% of the times it means you should have this loop at another level.

Comment: Don't understand... I would set the updated_balance to zero and then the month to 1 in an if statement... That if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I would also advise you to try to think on a higher level of abstraction, i.e. define different tasks and put them into their own functions. For example the check whether the `minimum_monthly_payment` is enough seem to be a separate task that can be refactored into its own function. Splitting problems into separate smaller ones helps to avoid entangling logic. It might seem much at start, but starting to think structurally as soon as possible is crucial to avoid habit of devising macaroni solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So in programming you can create functions. These are blocks of code that you can call from elsewhere that will execute what you put in them. For python the syntax looks like...

```
def function_name(parameter1, parameter2, parameterN):
    #function code here
    #optional return statement
    return parameter1 + parameter2
```

So what you could try is putting your while loop inside a function and if the while loop is successful, return true, and if it fails return false. Then in your main you can choose to redo the function if it returns false. So here is an example of how you could fix your problem.

```
def try_to_pay_off(payment, interest_rate, start_balance):
    month = 0
    updated_balance = start_balance

    while month <= 12:
        month += 1
        updated_balance = updated_balance * (1 + interest_rate) - payment
        if updated_balance <= 0:
            return True
    # will return false if it goes through 12 months and debt not payed off
    return False

def Main():
    balance = float(input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:"))
    annual_rate = float(input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:"))

    done = False
    monthly_payment = 100
    while not done:
        if try_to_pay_off(monthly_payment,annual_rate,balance):
            done = True
        else:
            monthly_payment += 10
    # after finding the monthly payment required
    print ("Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:", monthly_payment)
```

This way you keep running your function with new values until it finds a monthly payment that can pay off your balance with interest rate in one year.

Comment: Im really confused about the 'while not done:
        if try_to_pay_off(monthly_payment,annual_rate,balance):
            done = True' part.  Dont you need to add something after the function to qualify the IF statement, like IF function is less than 0 or whatever?

Comment: So in general yes you would put an operator to compare the value. But since the function is returning a boolean already, it kind of self evaluates. be cause saying [ if True: ] will execute and [ if False: ] will never execute. So you can just use the return value to evaluate. However you can still put [ if try_to_pay_off() == True: ] this is just longer.

Comment: thanks SimKev2!  I ended up with my own solution if you want to see above and maybe critique for me and compare to yours and maybe say why yours is better than mine or not or if it makes a difference.  thanks a lot already, you are a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 0):

First off, **welcome to StackOverflow**, and I hope you enjoy the world of programming. I have heard MIT OCW is a great resource, so best of luck to you and whatever you're going to do.

If I understand the question correctly, you must find the smallest minimum payment (which is the same across all twelve months) that will pay off the debt. (I currently don't have commenting privileges, so if I misunderstand the question, I'd appreciate it if you clarified.)

To answer your question in the title, to "re-initiate iteration," you would **create a second loop outside the first**. Here's some example code.

```
# given balance and annual_rate

monthly_interest_rate = annual_rate / 12.0
minimum_monthly_payment = 100

# debt_is_paid_off is a use for a variable called a one-way flag
debt_is_paid_off = False

while not debt_is_paid_off:
    updated_balance_each_month = balance
    # range is a neat little python trick to go from 1 to 12 easily
    for month in range(1, 13):
        # update the balance
        updated_balance_each_month *= (1 + monthly_interest_rate) 
        updated_balance_each_month -= minimum_monthly_payment

        # check if it's paid off
        if updated_balance_each_month <= 0:
            debt_is_paid_off = True
            print ("Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:", 
                minimum_monthly_payment)
            print ("Number of months needed:",month)
            print (round(updated_balance_each_month,2))
            # note that this only breaks out of the for-loop.
            # so we need debt_is_paid_off to exit out.
            break
    minimum_monthly_payment += 10
```

Note how there are two loops in the code. The outer loop keeps increasing which minimum payment to try until the debt is paid off, and the inner loop simulates paying off the debt by repeating twelve times.

However, the standard approach - just using the "break" keyword, as you did - doesn't work in Python if there are two loops. It only breaks out of the first. So we use this new variable, debt_is_paid_off, to get us out of that second loop.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks guys for the help but I ended up coming up with a solution myself (!!!).  I figured out that in the code I originally posted, it would do the calculation for month 1 then check to see if updated_balance_each_month was less than 0 and if not increase monthly minimum by 10 for each month after that until balance was equal to or below 0 instead of running through all 12 months and then increasing monthly minimum by 10.  so you can see that I added another IF statement so that monthly minimum only increased if month == 12 and balance was above 0 and it worked!  Now, can anyone tell me how I can add code here so that it shows up properly?  I click on the {} and then paste my code where it says so but it always comes up jumbled...

```
balance = float(input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:"))
annual_rate = float(input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal:"))

monthly_interest_rate = annual_rate / 12.0
minimum_monthly_payment = 100

updated_balance_each_month = balance * (1 + monthly_interest_rate) - minimum_monthly_payment

month = 1

while month <= 12:

    month += 1

    updated_balance_each_month = updated_balance_each_month * (1 + monthly_interest_rate) - minimum_monthly_payment

    if updated_balance_each_month <= 0:
        print ("Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:", minimum_monthly_payment)
        print ("Number of months needed:",month)
        print (round(updated_balance_each_month,2))
        break
    if month == 12 and updated_balance_each_month > 0:
        minimum_monthly_payment += 10
        month = 0
        updated_balance_each_month = balance
```

Comment: Before each line of code there should be at least 4 spaces. That is the outer indentation level then if you want to indent again you put another four spaces